# Parts of this Sentence

Tags: verbs, subjects, predicate

I have the following questions regarding this sentence.

> To train them is my cause.

1. What is/are the verb(s) in the sentence?

   My guess: *train*.
   Question: only *train* or *to train*?
2. What is subject and predicate?

   My guess: subject = *My cause*, predicate = *To train them*
3. What  the type of word (noun,pronoun,adjective,verb etc.) is *is*?

   My guess: verb

Comment: Hint: Your answers 1 and 3 are not consistent with each other.

Comment: yes, I think all my answers are wrong :/

Comment: I don't think they're all wrong -- you're definitely on the right track.  But, in listing the verbs in the sentence, you omit one word that you later say is a verb.  "Is" *is* a verb, so why didn't you mention it in your answer to question 1?

Comment: @Rico The subject is definitely Ash Ketchum.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is 3058846 C;

Comment: Start by figuring out was "is" is, and work your way out from there.

Comment: Also, #2 would be correct, *if* the sentence was "My cause is to train them." Both of these sentences mean the same thing, just with slightly different emphasis and prosody. However, identifying subject and predicate in this particular type of sentence depends on the order of words, so if you flip the sentence around the subject and predicate change too.

Comment: So finally i take that the verb is 'is to train' and subject is 'my cause' and predicate 'is to train them.'

Comment: In the sentence "My cause is to train them", the verb is just "is", the subject is "my cause", and the predicate is "is to train them". "To train them" is a noun phrase, specifically a predicate nominative. That isn't your sentence, however.

Comment: O.o the question is wrong?!

Comment: Tchrist so indenting by four spaces adds the fancy background here too? thanks for edit.

Comment: @Wlerin How can we be sure there's no inversion here? *Also a great piano is our guest tonight ...*. I mean, I don't think there is, but how could we be sure ....?

Comment: @Araucaria We can be sure by our inability to be sure. There's nothing to go on besides word order, and so word order rules. It'd be different if one of the phrases was an adjective or adverb (since the subject must be a noun phrase), or the verb itself required a specific kind of subject or predicate (e.g. a verb of motion preceded by a destination phrase "to Denver go we"), but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence has two clauses, and therefore two verbs.

Starting with the subordinate infinitive clause *(For me) to train them*, the verb is ***train***.
The subordinate clause is subject of the main clause, which has *is my goal* as its verb phrase,
with ***is***, an auxiliary form of *be*, as the only other verb in the sentence.

There are two predicates, since there's two clauses.
Respectively, ***train them*** and ***is my goal*** are the predicates (a different name for *Verb Phrase*;
the *to* in the subordinate clause is just an infinitive marker, not part of the verb phrase.)
The subject of *train them* is *(For me)*, which is deleted, like most infinitive subjects.
But it's clear from the main clause that the speaker intends training them personally.

Answer (score 2):

To train them -> Subject

is (be) -> verb

my cause -> complement

Comment: How did you figure this out? o.O

Comment: You can obviously see that 'is' is the verb. Then you can figure out the rest by the way the verb interacts with them.  http://www.towson.edu/ows/sentpatt.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a special sentence pattern with the verb to be. The most frequent type is:

A mouse 1 is 2 an animal 3.

Mr Smith 1 is 2 my English teacher 3.

Snow 1 is 2 white 3. Here the complement is an adjective.

The plates 1 are 2 in the cupboard 3. Here the complement is a noun group that is a where-indication.

1 subject,
2 verb (of the type linking verb)
3 complement (Various word classes are possible.)

Sentence patterns with the verb to be have a lot of variants.
In the subject position there can be a to-infinitive:

To err 1 is 2 human 3.

To train them 1 is 2 my cause 3.

Google shows a lot about sentence patterns or sentence structures. I don't know which are the best sites and if there is a site that has patterns only with to be and other linking verbs as to become, to stay/to remain.
One general site is:

http://www.really-learn-english.com/sentence-structure.html

Comment: How about *in the cupboard are the plates?*

Comment: If someone asks "where are the plates?" the natural answer would be "in the cupboard", because the repetition "The plates are in the cupboard" is unnecessary. But an answer such as "In the cupboard are the plates" would be very unlikely in such a situation. Perhaps someone might ask "What is in the cupboard", then an answer such as "In the cupboard are the plates (and not the cups) would be possible. - But perhaps I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: So my point's that the word order can't give us the whole story, because in *Here comes Bob*, it's Bob that's the subject - but it follows the verb. So it could be quite useful to put some subject finding tests in there?

Comment: Well, in my understanding a where-indication as "in the cupboard" or a simple local adverb such as "here" can't be a subject, except in sentences such as "in the cupboard is an adverbial" or "here is an adverb of position or destination". But I know there are other views.